# Remove a Specific Docker Image

Tags: docker

I am using docker for different projects. When I run the command:

```
sudo docker images
```

It shows list of images with labels but there are a few images with **no label or tag.**

[image: Here is a screenshot for reference]

I want to know:

1. What are these images with no label
2. How to delete these images (as these are taking a large amount of space)

Comment: In all likelihood, these images are from incomplete builds (your `docker build` errored out, and Docker left the last completed stage so that you could debug if needed),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Docker image with no label is sometimes referred to as a “dangling image”. These may be unused leftovers that have accumulated over time. You can remove any unused images all at once like this:

```
sudo docker image prune
```

You’ll get a standard message:

```
WARNING! This will remove all dangling images.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N]
```

Hit <kbd>Y</kbd> if you’re okay with the action.

To remove specific images, you can do this:

```
sudo docker image rm {image id}
```

You can remove multiple images by adding more IDs to the command. If any of the images are required by a container, then you’ll get a message like:

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository reference "Fedora Workstation" (must force) - container cd20b396a061 is using its referenced image 75835a67d134
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Just a little confusion: Will it show the error message if that project is not up? Like if I have executed sudo docker-compose down and after that I try to remove a docker image.

Comment: A container is separate from an image. So, if you are trying to remove an image that is required by any of your containers, then the message will appear 